# Spring JPA @OneToOne bidirectional null field

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have two classes one of the name is Customer and this Customer have CustomerAccount class instance. Like this;

```
@Entity
@Table(name="tbl_customer") 
public class Customer extends BaseModel {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6330478175909499801L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator="customer_s")
    @SequenceGenerator(name="customer_s", sequenceName="customer_s", allocationSize=1)
    @Column(name="id")
    private Integer id;

    @JoinColumn(name = "customer_account_id")
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "customer", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    private CustomerAccount customerAccount;

    public CustomerAccount getCustomerAccount() {
        return customerAccount;
    }

    public void setCustomerAccount(final CustomerAccount customerAccount) {
        if (customerAccount == null) {
            if (this.customerAccount !=null) {
                this.customerAccount.Customer(null);
            }
        } else {
            customerAccount.setCustomer(this);
        }
        this.customerAccount = customerAccount;
    }

    //..    
}

@Entity
@Table(name="tbl_customer_account")
public class CustomerAccount extends BaseModel {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3995542305560456290L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "customer_account_s")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "customer_account_s", sequenceName = "customer_account_s", allocationSize = 1)
    @Column(name="id")
    private Integer id;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @MapsId
    private Customer customer;

    //..

}
```

Here is my CustomerServiceImpl,

```
@Service
public class CustomerServiceImpl implements CustomerService {

    @Autowired
    private CustomerDao customerDao; 

    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, rollbackFor = Exception.class)
    private void saveOrUpdate(final CustomerResult result) throws Exception {
        CustomerMapper.getInstance().dtoToDomain(result.getDtoEntity(), result.getDomainEntity()); 
        setCustomerData(result);
        customerDao.save(result.getDomainEntity()); 
        result.updateDtoIdAndVersion();
    }

    private void setCustomerData(final CustomerResult result) throws Exception{
        final CustomerAccount customerAccount = new CustomerAccount();
        customerAccount.setCustomer(result.getDomainEntity());  
        result.getDomainEntity().setCustomerAccount(customerAccount);
    }

}
```

My problem is When I persist Customer, Customer and CustomerAccount persist to the database. but in Customer entity 'customerAccount' field is null. I referred this article also [bidirectional entity associations](https://vladmihalcea.com/jpa-hibernate-synchronize-bidirectional-entity-associations/)

Comment: You want the CustomerAccount ID to be identical to the CustomerId by using MapsId. So don't tell JPA that it should it should generate the ID using a sequence generator: it shouldn't. Remove `@GeneratedValue` and `@SequenceGenerator` from the account's id. Just as... in the article you linked to. And to make sure the ID is populated after saving, you need to flush(), not just save().

Comment: Why do you have @MapsId? I assume that you don't want that. So remove it.

Comment: If I remove '@MapsId', how I map the 'Customer' and 'CustomerAccount' entities ? @Simon

Comment: Remove that on the customer side: @JoinColumn(name = "supplier_account_id") and remove the @MapsId and then everything should work

Comment: unfortunately result is same @SimonMartinelli

Comment: I used 'org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository'. And there is no flush() operation. @JBNizet

Comment: You're using JPA. use a JPARepository. https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/JpaRepository.html#flush--